# When do you add or subtract vectors?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, vectors, velocity

so I have a question here:

> An airplane travelling initially at 240 m/s[28° s of e], takes 35 s to change its velocity to 220 m/s[28°e of s]. what is the average acceleration over this time interval?

I was told by my teacher to subtract the vectors, but how do you know when to subtract the vectors, and when to add them? What part of the question makes the person go, oh I should subtract instead of add them?

Comment: What is the definition of acceleration? Does it involve velocity? Does it involve subtraction or addition?

Comment: Re, "... _change_ its velocity..." When something changes, there's a _difference_ between what it was before the change, and what it is after the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of average acceleration:Change in velocity /time elapsed
$$\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$$

Note that it is change ,$v_f-v_i$,Final velocity -intial velocity.

Now, do you see why we subtract?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, acceleration is $d\vec{v}/dt$. In turn, by the definition of a derivative, $d\vec{v}/dt = (v_f - v_i)/dt$, where $v_i$ is the initial velocity and $v_f$ is the velocity at a short time $dt$ afterwards.

Since it's $v_f -v_i$ (instead of $v_f + v_i$), you subtract the vectors.